# How to flag the last struct in a binary file as "DELETED" in binary files, C

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fseek

I need to delete the last struct written in the file **file.dat** and flag it with the word `deleted`.
This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct s_cliente {
    int codice;
    char nome[10];
    char merce[10];
    float prezzo;
};

typedef struct s_cliente cliente;

cliente inserisciCliente(cliente c1);
void inserisciOrdine();
void stampaFile();
float calcolaPrezzo(char nome[10]);
void eliminaLast();

int main() {

    char nome[10];
    float prezzotot = 0;
    int opz = 0;
    
    do {
        printf("\nInserisci un'opzione: \n1)Inserisci un cliente\n2)Stampa i clienti all'interno del file\n3)Ricerca un cliente e calcola l'importo dovuto\n");
        scanf("%d", &opz);
        switch (opz) {
          case 1:
            inserisciOrdine();
            break;
          case 2:
            stampaFile();
            break;
          case 3:
            getchar();
            scanf("%s", nome);
            prezzotot = calcolaPrezzo(nome);
            if (prezzotot != 0) {
                printf("\nImporto dovuto dal cliente %s: %2.f euro", nome, prezzotot);
            } else {
                printf("\nCliente non trovato");
            }
            break;
          default:
            printf("\nOpzione non valida");
            break;
        }
    } while (opz != 5);    
    return 0;
}

cliente inserisciCliente(cliente c1) {
    printf("\nInserisci il codice: ");
    scanf("%d", &c1.codice);
    getchar();
    printf("Inserisci il nome: ");
    scanf("%s", c1.nome);
    getchar();
    printf("Inserisci la merce: ");
    scanf("%s", c1.merce);
    printf("Inserisci prezzo: ");
    scanf("%f", &c1.prezzo);

    return c1;
}

void inserisciOrdine() {
    FILE *foutput = fopen("file.dat", "ab");
    cliente c1;
    c1 = inserisciCliente(c1);
    fwrite(&c1, sizeof(c1), 1, foutput);
    fclose(foutput);
}

void stampaFile() {
    FILE *file_lettura = fopen("file.dat", "rb");
    if (file_lettura != NULL) {
        cliente c1;
        while (fread(&c1, sizeof(cliente), 1, file_lettura) == 1) {
            printf("Codice: %d, Nome: %s, Merce: %s, Prezzo: %.2f\n", c1.codice, c1.nome, c1.merce, c1.prezzo);
        }
        fclose(file_lettura);
    } else {
        printf("Errore nell'apertura del file per la lettura.\n");
    }
}

float calcolaPrezzo(char nome[10]) {
    float prezzotot = 0;
    FILE *file_lettura = fopen("file.dat", "rb");
    cliente c1;
    if (file_lettura != NULL) {
        while (fread(&c1, sizeof(cliente), 1, file_lettura) == 1) {
            if (strcmp(nome, c1.nome) == 0) {
                prezzotot += c1.prezzo;
            }
        }
        fclose(file_lettura);
    } else {
        printf("\nErrore nella lettura");
    }

    return prezzotot;
}
```

I know that I can use the function `fseek();`, I just don't really understand how to flag the struct as deleted.

Comment: I don't think this question is very clear. You wrote the code, you define the interpretation for whether a file is deleted or not. You could add a 'deleted' boolean flag to the file struct. Or you could give an existing field a special value that means deleted.

Comment: Why do you need to flag it rather than just removing it completely?

Comment: You can either overwrite it with "deleted".  This will complicate reading the data afterwards.  Or overload the `nome` or `merce` field.  Overloading fields like this bad design.  You are better off actually adding status flag to your struct, rewrite your data in the new format and set that flag.  If you cannot get of the deleted records could you move them to a different file?  One trick delete a record without rewriting the entire file is to copy the last record over the deleted record, then truncate the file with 1 record less.

Comment: The non-English program limits you can help you.

Comment: Why do you pass the uninitialized `c1` to `inserisciCliente`?  Use a local variable and return it (by value like now).

Comment: You open the data file in 3 different functions; one of which fails to do error check.  Consider open the file once in `main()` and pass it in as an argument to the functions that need it.  Another really good design is to separate i/o and business logic so maybe just accumulate changes in memory and write them all out when done.

Comment: What are the valid values for `codice` in the struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google translate tells me `int codice;` means "code" in English so you can possible use that field to encode your flag.  For example using -1 for delete?  This means your question is wrong as you indicated that you wanted use the word "delete".  If you go this route then you have to audit your code and handle this flag.  You probably don't want to print deleted records, and if you want to delete subsequent records then you want to skip ones already deleted.  Do you want to retain or overwrite deleted records when you subsequently add a new record?

I suggest you delete the record by truncating the file instead and with these other issues:

0. Eliminate the `struct` name as you don't use it.
1. Always use a maximum field with when reading strings with `scanf()` to avoid buffer overflow.
2. Use symbolic constants instead of magic values.
3. Always check the return value from `fopen()`.  You missed it one place so combined it one place and pass file handle to the functions that need it.
4. Update menu with the missing promntps.  Also, to make the output easier to read only show the menu once at start-up.
5. There is no point to passing the uninitialized variable `c1` to `inserisciCliente()` and returning it by copy.  Just use a local variable.
6. (Not fixed) Move the calculation from the the `switch` to it's own function.
7. (Not fixed) Check the return value of `scanf()` otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized variables.  See for example how I handled the `opz` variable which I also moved to reduce it's scope.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define LEN 9
#define DAT "file.dat"
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

typedef struct {
    int codice;
    char nome[LEN+1];
    char merce[LEN+1];
    float prezzo;
} cliente;

cliente inserisciCliente() {
    cliente c1;
    printf("Inserisci il codice: ");
    scanf("%d", &c1.codice);
    getchar();
    printf("Inserisci il nome: ");
    scanf("%" str(LEN) "s", c1.nome);
    getchar();
    printf("Inserisci la merce: ");
    scanf("%" str(LEN) "s", c1.merce);
    printf("Inserisci prezzo: ");
    scanf("%f", &c1.prezzo);
    return c1;
}

void inserisciOrdine(FILE *lettura) {
    fseek(lettura, 0, SEEK_END);
    cliente c1 = inserisciCliente();
    fwrite(&c1, sizeof(c1), 1, lettura);
}

void stampaFile(FILE *lettura) {
    fseek(lettura, 0, SEEK_SET);
    cliente c1;
    while (fread(&c1, sizeof(cliente), 1, lettura) == 1) {
        printf("Codice: %d, Nome: %s, Merce: %s, Prezzo: %.2f\n", c1.codice, c1.nome, c1.merce, c1.prezzo);
    }
}

float calcolaPrezzo(FILE *lettura, char nome[10]) {
    fseek(lettura, 0, SEEK_SET);
    float prezzotot = 0;
    cliente c1;
    while (fread(&c1, sizeof(cliente), 1, lettura) == 1) {
        if (strcmp(nome, c1.nome) == 0) {
            prezzotot += c1.prezzo;
        }
    }
    return prezzotot;
}

void delete(FILE **lettura) {
    if(fseek(*lettura, 0, SEEK_END)) {
        perror("");
        return;
    }
    long end = ftell(*lettura);
    if(!end) return; // empty
    if(ftruncate(fileno(*lettura), end - sizeof(cliente))) {
        perror("");
        return;
    }
    *lettura = freopen(NULL, "a+r", *lettura);
    if(!*lettura) {
        perror("");
        return;
    }
}

int main() {
    FILE *lettura = fopen(DAT, "a+b");
    if(!lettura) {
        perror("Errore nell'apertura del file per la lettura.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf(
        "Inserisci un'opzione:\n"
        "1)Inserisci un cliente\n"
        "2)Stampa i clienti all'interno del file\n"
        "3)Ricerca un cliente e calcola l'importo dovuto\n"
        "4)Delete\n"
        "5)Exit\n"
    );
    for(;;) {
        printf("> ");
        enum { INSERT=1, SHOW, CALC, DELETE, EXIT=5 } opz;
        int rv = scanf("%d", &opz);
        if(rv == EOF)
            break;
        if(rv != 1)
            continue;
        switch (opz) {
            case INSERT:
                inserisciOrdine(lettura);
                break;
            case SHOW:
                stampaFile(lettura);
                break;
            case CALC: {
                       char nome[LEN+1];
                       float prezzotot = 0;
                       getchar();
                       scanf("%" str(LEN) "s", nome);
                       prezzotot = calcolaPrezzo(lettura, nome);
                       if (prezzotot)
                           printf("\nCliente non trovato");
                       else
                           printf("\nImporto dovuto dal cliente %s: %2.f euro", nome, prezzotot);
                       break;
                   }
            case DELETE:
                   delete(&lettura);
                   break;
            case EXIT:
                   goto done;
            default:
                   printf("\nOpzione non valida");
                   break;
        }
    }
done:
    fclose(lettura);
    return 0;
}
```

```
Inserisci un'opzione:
1)Inserisci un cliente
2)Stampa i clienti all'interno del file
3)Ricerca un cliente e calcola l'importo dovuto
4)Delete
5)Exit
> 1
Inserisci il codice: 1
Inserisci il nome: 2
Inserisci la merce: 3
Inserisci prezzo: 4
> 1
Inserisci il codice: 2
Inserisci il nome: 3
Inserisci la merce: 4
Inserisci prezzo: 5
> 2
Codice: 1, Nome: 2, Merce: 3, Prezzo: 4.00
Codice: 2, Nome: 3, Merce: 4, Prezzo: 5.00
> 4
> 2
Codice: 1, Nome: 2, Merce: 3, Prezzo: 4.00
> 5
```